# Chartjs ignore values and draw chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, linechart

is there any way in Chart.js for ignoring some values in data array and draw the chart anyway without them? Labels option is a must have.
Here is example: https://codepen.io/rom4uk/pen/WNQjWEW?editors=0010

```
    <div class="line-chart">
        <div class="aspect-ratio">
            <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank's everybody

Comment: I see the nulls in your example,  just use spanGaps: true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i.e.

```
datasets: [{
            label: 'Custom Label Name',
            backgroundColor: gradient,
            spanGaps: true,
            pointBackgroundColor: 'white',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#911215',
            data: [50, null, 80, null, 54, 50]
    }]
```